# Add custom static method to auto generated codes in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, static-methods, t4, auto-generate

How can I add a custom static method to auto generated codes in EF6? (using model.tt)

```
public partial class tbl_Persons
{
    public static void MyMethod(int personID)
    {
    //my codes
    }

    public tbl_Persons()
    {

    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FatherName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Read more about [partial classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods)
2. Create new file
3. Place your code in this file:

   ```
   public partial class tbl_Persons
   {
       public static void MyMethod(int personID)
       {
           //my codes
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks. but I need to use (model.tt) to add a method to all entities automatically.

Comment: @RezaKarimnia you can modify model.tt as you want

Comment: Which line or method I should Modify ?